# How to test ant design Select and Option properly using jest?

Tags: antd

I am using Ant Design for my select form component and I would like to test the options value because the values will change dynamically based on the different choices that user made while filling.

`my-test.spec.js`

```
      let questionDropdown
      await waitFor(() => {
        questionDropdown = screen.getByRole('combobox', { name: 'Question'})
        expect(questionDropdown).toBeDefined()
      })
      fireEvent.click(questionDropdown)

      // Hoping to test the options after clicking on the select, but I can't find the options element on screen
      // expect(screen.getByText('question 1')).toBeDefined()
      // expect(screen.queryAllByRole('option').length).toEqual(2)
```

I found this issues in `antd` about how to mock the Select and Options components.

```
jest.mock('antd', () => {
  const antd = jest.requireActual('antd');

  const Select = ({ children, onChange }) => {
    return <select onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}>{children}</select>;
  };

  Select.Option = ({ children, ...otherProps }) => {
    return <option {...otherProps}>{children}</option>;
  }
  
  return {
    ...antd,  
    Select,
  }
}
```

but still have no luck getting my options tested.

Answer (score 6):

You can test it without mocking. See this example:

```
import { Select, SelectProps } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';

const { Option } = Select;

export type Period = 'days' | 'months' | 'years';

const ranges = [
  { name: 'Dia', duration: 'days' },
  { name: 'Mês', duration: 'months' },
  { name: 'Ano', duration: 'years' },
];

export type PeriodRangePickerProps = Pick<SelectProps<Period>, 'value' | 'onChange' | 'style'>;

const PeriodRangePicker = ({ value, onChange, style }: PeriodRangePickerProps) => (
  <Select style={style || { width: 90 }} showSearch optionFilterProp="children" {...{ value, onChange }}>
    {ranges.map(({ duration, name }) => (
      <Option key={duration} value={duration}>
        % {name}
      </Option>
    ))}
  </Select>
);

export default PeriodRangePicker;
```

```
import PeriodRangePicker from '@components/PeriodRangePicker/PeriodRangePicker';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('PeriodRangePicker', () => {
  it('should call onChange with correct values', async () => {
    const handleChangeStub = jest.fn();

    render(<PeriodRangePicker onChange={handleChangeStub} />);

    const periodSelect = screen.getByRole('combobox');

    await userEvent.click(periodSelect);

    await waitFor(() => screen.getByText('% Dia'));

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('% Dia'));

    expect(handleChangeStub).toBeCalledWith('days', expect.anything());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is work! However, I want to ask why the last two line need to use `fireEvent.click` instead of `userEvent.click`? I try to replace it with `userEvent.click` but it can not work...

Comment: Replace ```await userEvent.click(periodSelect);``` => ```userEvent.click(periodSelect)```
and ```await waitFor(() => screen.getByText('% Dia'));``` => ```await screen.findByText('% Dia')```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mocked it as such, your interaction with the `Select` component should be

```js
const questionDropdown = await screen.getByRole('combobox', { name: 'Question'});

act(() => {
    fireEvent.change(questionDropdown, { target: value: { CHANGE_VALUE } });
});
```

For testing the `Select` component without mocking, it should be something like this

```js
const questionDropdown = await screen.getByRole('combobox', { name: 'Question' });

act(() => {
    fireEvent.click(questionDropdown);
});

// basically, you should be able to find the elements of the 
// dropdown after you fire the click even on the select
const questionOneEle = await screen.getByText('question 1');

act(() => {
    fireEvent.click(questionOneEle);
});

// you can consider using jest-dom to run an assertion here
// at the top of your test file -> import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

expect(questionDropdown).toHaveValue(YOUR_EXPECTED_VALUE);
```

The annoying thing with testing this way, however, is that due to the way `antd` handles their `select` component, there's quite a bit of opacity to the dropdown items that gets rendered, which might make debugging failing tests a little difficult.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on how to test the options list?

Comment: @SamKahChiin to test the mocked or unmock implementation? The solution i provided is to test the mocked implementation. To test it unmocked, you will need to use the click events. Do you need an example?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I would like to test the list of available options in the select. I hope I can test it unmock but AntDesign doesn't allow me to do so. 
Appreciate if you can provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I added [a more complete example of a mock for the Ant Design Select component](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21080#issuecomment-738399118) which works great so far (in the middle of a 300 unit tests migration mocking antd Select :)). I placed this mock in a setupTests.js file in my project src folder (I'm using CRA).

With this kind of mock, you can test select options like this :

```
const options = Array.from(mySelect.querySelectorAll('option')).map(o => o.getAttribute('value');
expect(options).toEqual(['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];

expect(mySelect).toHaveValue('selectedValue');
```

This example only grabs options value attributes, you can also test `textContent` (displayed values), by modifying the function applied in `map`.

To interact with the select, as explained by [angkiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63010862/2295549), you just need to `fireEvent.change(mySelect, { target: { value: 'value2' } });`, and act() should not be necessary since [react-testing-library takes care of that for you](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/migrate-from-enzyme#using-act-and-wrapperupdate). If you still have issues with annoying warnings about using act, see https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your component like so to avoid the querySelector all

```
const elt = getByTestId('your-test-id').firstElementChild;
fireEvent.mouseDown(elt);
```

Now at this point you probably want to select an option from the list but there is an animation going on so the following code (that used to work in v3) will fail.

```
expect(getByText('Option from Select')).toBeVisible(); // FAILS !
```

You have 2 options, use toBeInTheDocument() or wait for the animation to be over by using waitFor(...)

Option 1: Faster but not totally accurate, I prefer to use this for simple use cases as it makes the tests faster and synchronous

```
expect(getByText('Option from Select')).toBeInTheDocument(); // WORKS !
```

Option 2: Slower as you need to wait for the animation to finish but more accurate for complex cases

```
await waitFor(() => expect(getByText('Option from Select')).toBeVisible()); // WORKS !
```